# Why there are no any link to my site in content of my email?

Tags: email, laravel-5

In my laravel 5.7 app I use snowfire/beautymail templates and themsaid/laravel-mail-preview plugin for testing of emails sending at my local laptop.

In content of my email I point to my site with url like

```
<p class="email_title">
  You sent contact us message at <a href="{{ $site_home_url }}" target="_blank" class="a_link"></a>{!! $site_name !!} site successfully !
</p>
```

I made check that these 2 variables are not empty, but checking email at my local disk when 
working at my local laptop with laravel-mail-preview enabled and sending emails using configured smtp there are no any link to my site
in content of my email.

I have smtp installed. 
In .env of my server app:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp 
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com 
MAIL_PORT=587 
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I check recieved emails on yahoo.com, gmail.com accounts.

Why links are not visible ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$site_name` is outside the `<a></a>` tag, so the link will be there but not visible because it has no content.

Change:

```
<p class="email_title">
  You sent contact us message at <a href="{{ $site_home_url }}" target="_blank" class="a_link"></a>{!! $site_name !!} site successfully !
</p>
```

to:

```
<p class="email_title">
  You sent contact us message at <a href="{{ $site_home_url }}" target="_blank" class="a_link">{!! $site_name !!}</a> site successfully !
</p>
```